# How to set custom variable in Twig to display raw

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

Does anyone know is there a nice and clear way to set up |raw filter on custom variable? In my specific example:

```
<tag {{ element.attributes|raw }}></tag>
```

this variable holds string: `'someAttribute="someValue"'`.

Without `|raw` it prints

```
<tag someAttribute=""someValue"/"></tag>
```

So all i want is to write some kind of extension with token parser? for all variables with name == 'attributes' that i dont need to use |raw filter on them everytime

Comment: If you want to write an extension with a token parser, what is the question exactly?

Comment: Actully i think i found better solution, going to write replacement function for Twig's escape filter. Where i check if variable is instance of class i want and then act like i want.